# How to efficiently remove consecutive same characters in a string

Tags: java, string

I wrote a method to reduce a sequence of the same characters to a single character as follows. It seems its logic is correct while there is a room for improvement in terms of performance, according to my tutor. Could anyone shed some light on this?
Comments of aspects other than performance is also really appreciated.

```
public class RemoveRepetitions {
    public static String remove(String input) {
        String ret = "";
        String last = "";
        String[] stringArray = input.split("");

        for(int j=0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
            if (! last.equals(stringArray[j]) ) {
                ret += stringArray[j];
            }
            last = stringArray[j];
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RemoveRepetitions.remove("foobaarrbuzz"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can improve the performance by using `StringBuilder` instead of using string as string operations are costlier. Also, the `split` function is also not required (it will make the program slower as well).
Here is a way to solve this:

```java
public static String remove(String input)
{
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder("");
    int N = input.length();
    int i = 0;

    while (i < N)
    {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        answer.append( c );
        while (i<N && input.charAt(i)==c)
            ++i;
    }
    return answer.toString();
}
```

The idea is to iterate over all characters of the `input` string and keep appending every new character to the answer and skip all the same consecutive characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main difference affecting performance is the cost of `String#equals()` and `ret += stringArray[j]` but not algorithm, isn't it?

Comment: @uemurm Yes, your approach is completely fine. Just the various string operations are the cause of performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

Possible change which you could think of in your code is:

```
Time Complexity: Your code is achieving output in O(n) time complexity, which might be the best possible way.

Space Complexity: Your code is using extra memory space which arises due to splitting.

Question to ask: Can you achieve this output, without using the extra space for character array that you get after splitting the string? (as character by character traversal is possible directly on string).
```

I can provide you the code here but, it would be great if you could try it on your own, once you are done with your attempts

you can lookup for the best solution here (you are almost there)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-consecutive-duplicates-string/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, it is much better to access the characters in the string using method `String::charAt` or at least by iterating a `char` array retrieved with `String::toCharArray` instead of splitting the input string into `String` array.

However, Java strings may contain characters exceeding [basic multilingual plane of Unicode](https://www.sttmedia.com/unicode-basiclingualplane) (e.g. emojis , Chinese or Japanese characters etc.) and therefore `String::codePointAt` should be used.  Respectively, `Character.charCount` should be used to calculate appropriate offset while iterating the input string.

Also the input string should be checked if it's null or empty, so the resulting code may look like this:

```java
public static String dedup(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    int prev = -1;
    int n = str.length();
    System.out.println("length = " + n + " of [" + str + "], real length: " + str.codePointCount(0, n));
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
        
        int cp = str.codePointAt(i);

        if (i == 0 ||  cp != prev) {
            sb.appendCodePoint(cp);
        }
        prev = cp;
        i += Character.charCount(cp); // for emojis it returns 2
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

A version with `String::charAt` may look like this:

```java
public static String dedup2(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    int n = str.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
    sb.append(str.charAt(0));
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i - 1)) {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The following test proves that `charAt` fails to deduplicate repeated emojis:

```java
System.out.println("codePoint: " + dedup (" hello"));
System.out.println("charAt:    " + dedup2(" hello"));
```

Output:

```java
length = 20 of [ hello], real length: 13
codePoint:  helo
charAt:     helo
```